# Prove $x $ is not an element of $E^0$ if and only if $B_r(x) \cap E^c \neq \emptyset $ for all $r> 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Prove: $x \notin E^0$ if and only if $B_r(x) \cap E^c \neq \emptyset $ for all $r> 0$.

Proof: I just need help with converse part.

Converse: Suppose $B_r(x) \cap E^c \neq \emptyset $ for all $r> 0$, then $x $ is not an element of  $E^0$ because $E$ is open . Hence $x $ is not an element of  $E^0$ if and only if $B_r(x) \cap E^c \neq \emptyset $ for all $r> 0$.

Is this correct? Any help would really help. Thanks

Comment: How did you infer that E is open? $E^0$ (if as I understood it is interior of E) is open.

Comment: Or did you forget to mention that it is open?

Comment: I am only given $E $ is a subset of $ X$. where the boundary of E is equal to closure of E \ interior of E. I I was just assuming, but I don't really know

Comment: So I can just mention since x is not an element of the interior of E, by definition , x is an element of the boundary of E, thus $B_r(x) \cup E^c \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: Clarifying: $E^0$-interior of E, $E^c$-complement of E isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I mislead you in the comments:

Converse: Suppose $B_r(x)\cap E^c\ne\emptyset \forall r>0$.

$x\notin E^0$ because **$E^0$ is open** (and hence we can find an open ball about x such that $B_r(x)\subset E^0$).

---

**Edit** I would prefer to write it like this;

Converse: Suppose $B_r(x)\cap E^c\ne\emptyset \forall r>0$.

Suppose $x\in E^0$. Since $E^0$ is open, for some r, we have $B_r(x)\subset E^0$ by the definition of open sets, contradicting our assumption. Hence $x\notin E^0$.

Comment: You are welcome! :)